# English numbers in non-English subtitle

Tags: microsoft-word, unicode, subtitles, utf-8, farsi

I wrote my subtitle in a word document & saved it as a txt file with UTF-8 encoding. Then I changed its format from txt to srt manually. my subtitle language is Persian.

I put it in the same folder of the movie with the same name. When playing movie, everything is OK, but numbers typed in the subtitle appear in English when playing the movie, not in Persian. 
any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: If you open the file in Notepad (not Word), what numbers does it show?

Comment: it appears English also in notepad and notepad++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Were you expecting ancient Persian numbers?

[image]

The problem is with MS Word, and how you are entering the characters.
When you type into word, using your keyboard even with your language set to Farsi, the numbers are being entered as ASCII.  If using word, you will need to insert numbers by typing Alt+XXXX where XXXX is UTF-8 code of the number character.

THIS WILL ALLOW true Farsi numerals:

صف, يکد,و

You can find info on how to type them on various systems on http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/06f0/index.htm up to http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/06f9/index.htm